# Posting a hidden field with whitespace removes content after whitespace

Tags: javascript, php, post, hidden-field

Am posting a hidden field e.g. value: 'this is the example format'.
When getting the results in $_POST['name'], the variable's value is cut down to only 'this'.
Which means everything after a whitepsace is removed..
Any ideas?

PS Am using htmlspecialchars on the hidden field's value to replace whitespaces with formatted data, but it's not helping.

PSS I am thinking it is my own fault, since there is nothing to be found about it on the net, so there might very well be no solution.

Comment: We would need to see an example of the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

Guess you have to escape quotes: `"` to `\"` within your "value".

Answer (score -1):

I cannot seem to reproduce your error. Could you post the code of your form, maybe something else is wrong?

I got a good result, whatever I try, for example:

```
<form method="post" action="./test.php">
<input type="hidden" value="<?=htmlspecialchars('this is the format')?>" name="test" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

// Blah blah code, then result    
echo $_POST['test']; // gives this is the format
```

Also the other way, encode AFTER post, gives OK result.

```
<form method="post" action="./test.php">
<input type="hidden" value="this is the format" name="test" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

// Blah blah code, then result    
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['test']); // gives this is the format
```