# Django template variable removes content after whitespace

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am having this very confusing issue and I could only find someone who had the same issue 9 year ago but it wasn't solved : [Posting a hidden field with whitespace removes content after whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911935/posting-a-hidden-field-with-whitespace-removes-content-after-whitespace).

First of all I'm very new to programming so pardon me if this is a very obvious issue and if my bug is very ugly !

Basically I am trying to pass the content of a variable through the value parameter of an input tag inside of a form. This variable contains strings separated by whitespaces ("test space space")

My goal is to then manipulate this data in a view through request.POST

The issue is that the first word gets passed just fine but anything after the first whitespace isn't passed to the database.

Note that I am using the same variable elsewhere in the same template and the entire title is displayed without issue

Here is my view :

```
@login_required
def watchlist(request):
    user = request.user
    all_watched_auctions = WatchedAuction.objects.all()
    user_watched_auctions=all_watched_auctions.filter(user_id=user.id)
    if request.method == "POST" :
        auction_info = request.POST
        user_id = auction_info.get('user_id')
        auction_id = auction_info.get('auction_id')
        title = request.POST.get('title')
        # #creating a watched auction 
        auction_to_watch = WatchedAuction(user_id=user_id, auction_id=auction_id, is_watched=True, title=title)

        # #preventing duplicates
        if auction_id not in user_watched_auctions:
            auction_to_watch.save()

    test = user_watched_auctions.values_list("auction_id", flat=True)

    
    active_listings = Listing.objects.filter(status="ACTIVE")
    return render(request,"auctions/watchlist.html",{
        "watchlist" : test,
        "listings" : active_listings,
        "user" : user,
    })
```

And here is the template. You can skip to the end. That's where the troublesome form is  :

```
{% extends "auctions/index.html" %}

{% block title %} {{listing.title}}{% endblock %}

{% block h2 %}
{% if listing.status == "ACTIVE" %}
    <h2>Listing is active</h2>
{% else %}
    <h2>Listing is inactive</h2>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}


<div>
<div>{% block test1 %}
    {% if test.id == listing.id %}
    {{block.super}}
</div>
<div>

</div>
{% if listing.author_id == user_id and listing.status == "ACTIVE" %}
</div>

<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    <a href="">
    
        <button> Close listing </button>
    </a>
</form>

{% endif %}

{% if listing.author_id != user_id and listing.status == "ACTIVE" %}
<form action="{% url 'watchlist' %}" method="post" value="test.id">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value={{user_id}}>
    <input type="hidden" name="auction_id" value={{listing.id}}>
    <input type="hidden" name="is_valid" value=True>
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value={{listing.title}}>
    <button type="submit"> add to watchlist</button>
        
    
</form>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks a lot to anyone taking the time to help me !

Comment: Use double quotes to wrap values, i.e. `value="{{listing.title}}"`. Your browser can't know whether `bar` is a separate attribute of the `input` tag in `<input value=foo bar>`.

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks a lot for your answer ! The issue was indeed as stupid as I thought it might be. I really thought putting the variable in quotes would put {{listing.title}} in the post request and not its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Probably this is due to lack of quotes between actual value **value="actual_value"**. You can use single quotes or double quotes according to your html. Please try this way. It may work.

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{user_id}}">
<input type="hidden" name="auction_id" value="{{listing.id}}">
<input type="hidden" name="is_valid" value="True">
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{listing.title}}">
<button type="submit"> add to watchlist</button>
```